# simple (I think) combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Question.**  How many ways can you partition $n$ distinct items into $k$ distinct groups?

It seems like there should be a standard formula for this, but I could not find it.

For instance, suppose you have a 10-page document that need printing, and three printers to print the pages.  How many ways could you assign the pages of the document to the five printers?  (For instance, you could assign pages 1,2,10 to printer A; pages 3-9 to printer B, and nothing to printer C.)

Thanks!

Comment: Does each group have to be non-empty?

Comment: It is worth pointing out also the related problem where you explicitly don't want any of the groups to be empty.  For that, see the [stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), the result being $k!{n\brace k}$.  For other similar problems where certain objects are or are not distinct and you do or do not require empty etc... see [Stanley's Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that was already covered with the example given... "*For instance... and nothing to printer C*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the choice to place the first item in one of the $k$ different groups. Similarly for the other $n-1$ items.
So we can  partition $ n$ distinct items into $k$ distinct groups in $k^n$ ways.

Comment: Oh, duh.  Geez...